# How to del in redis with regular expressions that keys does not match a list of express?

Tags: redis

I tried to delete lines in redis, I first search keys to make sure my expression is right.

get keys that start with `sess:` :

```
keys sess:*   //I get return as I expect
```

get keys that not start with `sess:` :

```
keys ^(sess:)* //I get empty list, not as expect
keys [^sess:]* //I get list that not start with s or e or :, not as expect
```

get key that not start with `sess:` and `brand:`

```
keys [^(sess:|brand:)]* //I get list that not start with s or e or : or b and so on, not as expect
```

Could any one help me with the list that I did not get the right return as I expect?

Answer (score 0):

If you will refer the the documentation of the `keys` command [here](http://redis.io/commands/keys) you will notice that the parameter

> Supported glob-style patterns: h?llo matches hello, hallo and hxllo
>   h*llo matches hllo and heeeello h[ae]llo matches hello and hallo, but
>   not hillo h[^e]llo matches hallo, hbllo, ... but not hello h[a-b]llo
>   matches hallo and hbllo Use \ to escape special characters if you want
>   to match them verbatim.

Therefore regex is not supported

As mentioned in the documentation:

> If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace,consider using SCAN or sets

[Link to glob-style patterns here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

Comment: so actually not contains a character works but not contains string will not work? Anyway, I tried `keys *[^:]*` but it does not return as expect.

Comment: what are you trying to get? all keys that contains `^` or `:`?

Comment: I want to get all keys not contains "sess:" and "brand:". If I understand your reply correct, it is impossible to do that? so I think I can just do that NOT contain `:` but it does not work as I expect.

Comment: did you try `keys "*[!:]*"`?

Comment: so try using `SCAN` instead of `KEYS`.
anyway, it looks like the data is not stored in a way that allows you to do this operation, maybe you should think of using different types in redis

Comment: well, I tried `scan 0 match *^[:]* count 1000` and it return a empty list. `scan 0 match *:*` works fine as it also works with `keys`